# Problem with importing Python modules from specific folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a code in *`Python-Part/Modules&Packages/salute.py`*

```
def say_hello(name):
    print(f'Hello {name}')


fruits = {
    'name': 'Grapes',
    'color': 'Green'
}
```

I have a code in *`Python-Part/Modules&Packages/my_module.py`*

```
import salute
from salute import fruits

salute.say_hello('Rafi')

print(fruits['name'])
```

When I put them in the *`Python-Part`* directory they were working fine but when I move them into *`Python-Part/Modules&Packages`*, *`my_module.py`* is not importing *`salute.py`*.

Now, **I want to know why this is happening and how to overcome from it?**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider including whatever error traceback you get in your post.

Comment: The information provided is not enough to give a definitive answer, other than guessing. Please see the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to help us help you. In specific, how do you run your code?

Comment: Try adding `_init__.py` file in every folder

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python 2 treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file.

So, try to add `__init__.py` to package directories you intend to use.

Comment: This is *not* the case in python 3. A directory without `__init__.py` is a namespace package which, for the purpose of this issue, will behave like a normal package.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ma'am.